# Docker : directory mapped in volume is not created with same user of host

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-volume

i'm running a docker container inside my server .

in my server (host) i ve this folder : `/opt/myapp/myFolder`

where myFolder has **755 permissions** and `myuser:mygroup` **ownership**

I'm using docker-compose to run my container , thus i'm mounting that same volume

```
mycontainer:
    ...
    volumes:
    - /opt/myapp/myFolder:/opt/myapp/myFolder
    ...
```

The probleme that , inside my container , my directory "**myFolder**" still having the same host permissions (755) but not the same ownership

and the ownership looks like this `65534:65534`

this results on **permission denied** in some other treatment inside this folder.

normally inside the container "**myFolder**" still keeping the same host ownership .

**Note** : tthe user `myuser` and the group `mygroup` do exist inside the container.

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 1):

Docker doesn't create users and groups to match the mounted folder's ownership.
You can add the user inside your container to the folder's group, using the group id (GID).

Check out "[Docker and file system permissions](https://medium.com/@nielssj/docker-volumes-and-file-system-permissions-772c1aee23ca)" article.